# What is considered as EOF in stdin?

Tags: c, visual-studio, eof

My Visual Studio still awaits input even after I keep entering a newline.

For example:

```
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
{
   // do something
}
```

What should I enter that sends EOF to Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

You can send an `EOF` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (for Linux) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (for Windows) systems.

To elaborate, when `fgetc()` is waiting for an input from *empty* `stdin`, this key combination will simulate the `EOF`. In case, the `stdin` is not empty, you have to use the key combination twice (once to help flush the `stdin`, another to actually send the `EOF`).

Comment: @WeatherVane At this moment I have no idea and I don't have a windows system handy, will update you after I try.

Comment: Oops dear readers I had already removed: "Do you know why `scanf` requires *three* such sequences?"

Comment: Control-D doesn't really send an EOF.  It forces the current pending console input operation to return immediately with whatever has been typed up to that point.  A lot of software assumes that the only reason an input request will return without reading any bytes is that it has reached the end, but control-D has no special meaning aside from cooked-mode consoles, unlike control-Z which MS-DOS interprets as an EOF indication if encountered within a text file.